# Focus issue in Carousel

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I'm using Nuka Carousel in my component, the input element doesn't get focused unless I add an explicit focus to it on an onClick function.

ex: Unless I add focus explicitly input does not get focused.

```
onClick={() => {
inputRef && inputRef.current && inputRef.current.focus();
}}
```

The problem is by adding focus I'm not able to click or change my cursor position elsewhere using mouse.

Comment: Try this.focus();

Comment: @HamendraSunthwal I already have a focus. When there is focus I will not be able to move the cursor's position. I want to solve this issue